# How do I write a text in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

I have no idea of visualforce, but Need to have a small text page as an Agenda on a Dashboard

### The Text is

**WSTS Power Management**

J6a = Linear Regulators
J6b = Switching Regulators
J6d = Voltage Regulators
J6f = Supervis, Sequencing & Control
J6g = Battery Charging & Management
J6e = Other Power Management

---

How do I translate this into a Visualforce page?

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce allows for standard HTML to be used. This means that you can find a basic cheat sheet or guide for HTML like http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/html_cheatsheet/ to help you format your text. You can then place the content in your Visualforce page. You are not required to use any Visualforce tags other than the wrapping  tag that Salesforce will add for you when you create the new page.